# How to alter Python function that causes TypeError in flask

Tags: python, flask, typeerror

I'm aware there are other questions in the same regard, but they didn't help me.
When I open my flask project and run it the first time I get an error:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

If I delete this function, run flask, execute the rest of the python code from the index.html, paste the function back in and run it, everything works fine:

```
def select_zone():
    
    zones = request.form.get("select_zone")
    if zones == "Z1":
        return open_zone1()

    if zones == "Z2":
        return open_zone2()
```

In another post the solution was explained this way:

> The error indicates that the function is not complete because it
> misses the return instruction. Any view function must return
> something.

Well, my function returns something, just not the render_template, because I don't need it there. How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Could you please post the code of open_zone1() and open_zone2() ?

Comment: Can zones be another value? If so, you won't return anything.

Comment: What happens if `zones = "42"` ? Your function returns nothing. You need to return a valid view - maybe some error page - in whatever case might happen.

Comment: @Just learned it The values for zones are coming from a dropdown menu in index.html. TheTypeError occurs when I open the index.html

Comment: Do you init `zones`?

Comment: @Patrick Artner If I hardcode something to zones `zones = 42` the error is the same

Comment: @Just learned it no, but I just tried it and it doesn't change anything. I tried `zones = 0` inside of the function

Comment: You have to init it with either "Z1" or "Z2". These are the only values where you function returns something which is not None.

Comment: @Just learned it I tried to assign with Z1 but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `zones` is another value (as described by Just learned it and Partick Artner in the comments), then the function will not return anything. Specifically, you say this error triggers when you open the `index.html`. This probably means that, since zones is a value from a dropdown, it is not included in the request.

If a key is not found, `request.form.get()` returns None. Since you don't check for this value, there is no way for the `select_zone` function to return anything. I'd advise you to think about multiple scenario's here. I'll write them down in Python below.

```py
from flask_api.status import HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

def select_zone():
    zones = request.form.get("select_zone")
    if zones is None:
        # Zones not in request, what do you do? Throw an error,
        # return all zones, or just return silently? For example:
        # `return f"Missing `select_zone` parameter", HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`
        # returns a 400 (Bad Request) error

    if zones == "Z1":
        return open_zone1()

    if zones == "Z2":
        return open_zone2()

    # Zones is not None, Z1 or Z2, thus it must be some other
    # unforeseen value. This is probably where you need to throw
    # an error.
    return f"Invalid zone {zones}", HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```